# Vuetify v-dialog - Dynamic width

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

is it possible to make the v-dialog have dynamic width? Currently the v-dialog by default has dynamic height which makes it shorten and lengthen depending on the length of content.

But can this be done with width?

I have a v-dialog that contains 4 tabs. 3 of those tabs don't require much width but the last tab contains a table so I'd like the dialog to widen as far as it needs to, to cater for the table, and then shorten again when clicking on either of the first 3 tabs.

Vuetify v-dialog: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs

Comment: could you create a codepen for this? You can try playing around with max and min width, or try stuff with fill but I can't tell without your code

Answer (score 33):

Setting width to "unset" seems to work, haven't discovered any negative side effects yet.

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="unset">
    <YourDialogContent></YourDialogContent>
</v-dialog>
```

or CSS

```
.v-dialog {
    width: unset;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, because not setting any width at all stretched my dialogs to fullscreen width automatically. Thank you!

Comment: Bullseye!!!!!!!

Answer (score 13):

### For Desktop

> so I'd like the dialog to widen **as far as it needs to**, to cater for the table, and then shorten again when clicking on either of the first 3 tabs.

For desktop, we can set dynamic width for `v-dialog` based on contents inside the dialog easily, by manually setting the `width="auto "` (with extra space).

```
<template>
  <v-dialog width="auto ">
    ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

### For Mobile

Due to limited space, full-screen dialogs may be more appropriate for mobile devices than dialogs used on devices with larger screens. But need to set dialog to full-screen in mobile devices only. We can easily set dynamic full-screen using Vuetify [breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/) like:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog :fullscreen="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly">
    ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

### Final Version

We can combine both the logics into one like:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog width="auto " :fullscreen="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly">
    ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

[**Working Demo**](https://codepen.io/palash1/full/xxZxqro) | [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/palash1/pen/xxZxqro?editors=1010)

**On Desktop**

- If we open the dialog using the click me button, we can see the dialog has a small width as the content of tab 1 & 2 is very small. But if we click on tab 3, which has a large data table, you can see the dialog width and height automatically increases. You can toggle between tabs and can see this again.

**On Mobile**

- If you open this demo on mobile, you can see the dialog is opening in full-screen by default and the width is constant.

Comment: Although this solution works, I would advice against using it. The width value "auto " is not supported by vuetify and is just an invalid value. You could even use width="asdf" and the behavior would be -unintentionally- the same. As so, there is no guarantee that your code will keep working in future vuetify versions.

Answer (score 5):

Write custom css rules and not set `width` or `max-width` props. e.g.:

I use a custom class in order to not apply rules to all `v-dialog`:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" content-class="v-dialog--custom">
   <!-- dialog content -->
</v-dialog>
```

And create your custom rules:

```
.v-dialog--custom {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .v-dialog--custom {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

You can see this on codepen: https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/BajByxx

Comment: How did you calculate that for a screen to be desktop it should be 768px or larger?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this part?:

```
<v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
    width="500"
>
```

If so, why just don't remove the `width="500"` part and leave without one? I tested and it stretches dynamically. This option is not required and nothing is breaking if you remove it.

In case I misunderstood something, please feel free to add more details.

Comment: That's correct but if I remove width, then the dialog stretches the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what are you searching is the **fullscreen (bool)** property or depending on the needs the **max-width (Number)** property.

By setting one of those you control the width of the v-dialog depending on the surrounding element. The surrounding element width can be adjusted via css, e.g. flexbox.

Comment: Currently I have max-width set to 900px which caters for the table but when opening another table, the dialog doesn't adjust and become narrower. It's fixed on 900px constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use what scientists are using.

Make `width` as a computed variable, and then return your value based on the breakpoints.
If you want to set width dynamically based on the contents in the dialog then just modify the width function to return the `width` based on the contents.
Copied from vuetify site: [LINK](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service)

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" :width="width">
  <v-img src="~~~"></v-img>
</v-dialog>
<script>
  ...
  computed:{
    width() {
      switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
        case 'xs': return 220
        case 'sm': return 400
        case 'md': return 500
        case 'lg': return 600
        case 'xl': return 800
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: However, this is far from what vuetify is promising. It comes with tons of pre-defined classes and attributes to use in many different spots to control margins, paddings, offsets and col-spans in a grid based on breakpoints, but the width of a dialog must be controlled using some hacky computed property with fixed widths!? I tried to have a card inside a dialog and control it like v-col and v-row to no avail ...